# Non consumable in-app purchse using MKstorekit4?

Tags: iphone

I have an Iphone application in which i am using two types of purchases.Non consumable products and a subscription.For subscription i have to use mkstorekit4 anyway.So i need to implement the nonconsumable also in the storekit4.Anybody knows the steps to integrate nonconsumable products with mkstorekit4.Can anybody help me.

Comment: Warning: You are unlikely to get your app approved for subscription based purchases with non-consumable products. Apple is looking for a strong correlation between "price per consumption" like price per magazine issue or price per newspaper. In these cases there is a clear piece of content that didn't exist before that is now being delivered as part of a subscription. SAAS offerings generally don't count as no new functionality, capability or content is being delivered. In that case they'd prefer you release a new app or make a one time in-app purchase for added features.

Comment: Have a look on this..http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/StoreKitGuide.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As form me,if you've already managed how to add auto renew in your app, you are a guru of in-app,so adding a non-consumble would as easy as a pie,even without a MkStoreKit.

You just make a purchase and save it to UserDefaults.

And with MK you just add it to non-consumable part of your MK plist and add a couple of lines of code-and it's done)
Just a button,that makes a purchase,i think)

**Update**
This article just confirms, what i told.

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/using-mkstorekit-in-your-apps/

**Configuring for Non consumables : 
Non-consumables need no extra configuration. Just enter the list of product ids in the plist file.**
For checking whether the user has purchased the feature, you can call a function like,

```
if([MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:kFeatureID]) { //unlock it }
```

To purchase a feature, just call

`[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:kFeatureAId onComplete:^(NSString* purchasedFeature) { NSLog(@"Purchased: %@", purchasedFeature); } onCancelled:^ { NSLog(@"User Cancelled Transaction"); }];`

Comment: return expiresDate > [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]; always fails when i am testing in the device .do u know why?is it due to the country change?ie i am testing from india

Comment: Don't think so, because [NSDate date] is in GMT,and expiresDate,i believe,too.

Comment: but when i am commenting that only i am getting the subscribed view.i am not getting it even if i am getting status0

Comment: and  i also find that expiredate value is always less

Comment: Am I in chat name?)What do you mean?)

Comment: r u with the same name or anynickname is there.thats i mean

Comment: r u there now. am not finding ur name in the chatlist